# The kernel of what morphism is the commutator?

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

The kernel of a morphism is always normal to the group by the first isomorphism theorem. The commutator of a group is normal. Therefore if $G$ is my group and $C(G)$ is its commutators (and their products) is there some morphism $\phi$ such that $Kern(\phi) = C(G)$?

Comment: Just a comment, the group to which Noah is referring is called the [abelianization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator_subgroup#Abelianization) of your original group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes - in general, there's a simple recipe for finding a homomorphism from $G$ with kernel equal to $N$, whenever $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. Presumably you know how to form the **quotient group** $G/N$; can you think of any homomorphisms from $G$ to $G/N$ that might have kernel $N$?

Comment: Are you saying $\phi \colon g \mapsto gN$? That doesn't seem very satisfying. In fact it almost seems circular. If I wanted to show that the commutator subgroup is normal, could I say $\phi \colon g \mapsto gC(G)$ has $Ker \phi = C(G)$ therefore $C(G)$ is normal? Couldn't I say that with any subgroup?

Comment: @JorgeRodriguez That is indeed the right homomorphism. But it's not circular, and in particular it doesn't work for non-normal subgroups - try an example . . .